# Using $_SESSION["attribute"] in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, security, change-password

Is it ok to write this in javascript from a security point of view?

```
var u = <?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?>;
```

**(background):**
If I use it in a change password script in PHP with ajax in JS on background and I want to use this part of code cause in PHP page there is a form with `oldpassword`, `newpassword`, `newpasswordcheck` and the user is logged in and in `$_SESSION["username"]` there is a nick of that logged user and for changing the password I need old and new password which I get form inputs and the username of the user who execute the code which is in `$_SESSION["username"]` which bring us to that line of my code.

So the question is if it's OK to just echo that session value to my javascript variable?

Comment: if the username is not sensitive to your system, then there may not be problem with that

Comment: You missed out echo... var u = <?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?>

Comment: @Gavin actually yes and also the ; at the end sry, edited the question, but it was meant with the echo ofcourse.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, there is absolutely no need to do this. Its a session for a reason. If the user needs to change his/her password when the form is submitted you can grab the currently logged in user within PHP, thus eliminating the exposure of the username (even if it is just the username).

If you are getting confused because you are using AJAX then you can still access the currently logged in user as that user's browser/client is still performing the request, thus passing the cookie to identify the session.

It seems like you are overcomplicating this process, sorry if I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

That will only work if `$_SESSION['username']` is a number, which it almost certainly isn't.

```
var u = <?=json_encode($_SESSION['username'])?>;
```

[`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode) will make it safe to dump in js.

Comment: You probably mean this var u = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['username']) ?>; Do you?

Comment: well it's not a number, but why it won't work with not number content?

Comment: Using `<?=` is the same as `<?php echo`, it is just short hand syntax.

Comment: Why won't it work? Does `var u = herp a derp;` look like valid JavaScript to you?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol so json_encode will make from your var u = herp a derp; this: var u = "herp a derp"; ?

Comment: In this case, yes. But `json_encode` is extrmely powerful. It can take *almost any* PHP variable (except Resources) and make it so you can dump them in JavaScript.